# Why does this function expect a semicolon only on IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vue.js

I'm working on some vuejs code for IE 11 compatibility. And I keep seeing an expected semicolon error with this function:

```
chemicalFilters: function (chemical) 
{            
  var max = 0;
  var min = 100;
  for (var component of this.components)
  {
     if(component.component_name == chemical)
     {
       if (max < component.component_value)
         max = component.component_value;
       if(component.component_value != 0 && min > component.component_value)
         min = component.component_value;
     }
  }

  if(max == 0 && min == 100)
    min = max;
  else
  {
    min = Math.round(min*100);
    max = Math.round(max*100);
  }

  this.component_filters.push({component_name: chemical, range:[min,max], min:min, max:max, originalRange:[min,max]});
},
```

Specifically this line:

```
if(component.component_name == chemical)
```

Comment: `for ... of` is not supported in IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't in the line you cited, but the line above it. The `for...of` construct was introduced in ECMAScript 2015, which is not fully supported by IE11. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility):

[image: Browser Compatibility]

You could use a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile this into backward-compatible code, so this:

```
for (var component of this.components) {
  //...
}
```

Would be transpiled to something like this (depending on your settings):

```
var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
  for (var _iterator = this.components[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
    //...

    var component = _step.value;
  }
} catch (err) {
  _didIteratorError = true;
  _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
  try {
    if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return != null) {
      _iterator.return();
    }
  } finally {
    if (_didIteratorError) {
      throw _iteratorError;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your opinion on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach ?

Comment: @TheConstructor `forEach` is invaluable, especially paired with other methods like `filter`, `reduce`, or `Object.entries`. I generally prefer to use [functional constructs](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) rather than imperative ones wherever possible.

Comment: I was more thinking about whether or not it would be a cross-browser compatible solution to OPs problem. Know of any catch?